# Multi-CPU aws lambda / cloud function equivalent

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-functions

I want to run some code in the form of a AWS Lambda / Google Cloud function but need 8 CPU cores (otherwise it takes too long to run).
At the moment I have an instance running 24/7 but it's rarely used so it is a waste of money.

Is there any way or a workaround to do that in AWS or Google Cloud?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you trigger your job? Is it an HTTP request? Do you need a synchronous http response? Or the job can continue to run in background (and you will be able to get the answer later, with another request)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serverless computing products generally use cheap, commodity hardware to achieve massive scalability, while keeping the product affordable.  I would expect this will not change any time soon.  As such, these products are not suitable for heavy computation.

In general, if you need high end hardware for your compute jobs, you pay daily/hourly rates to keep those services running, as they do not scale up and down quickly as required by serverless options.  There is no avoiding paying these rates if you need this level of compute.

You are certainly free to combine these offering.  For example, it's perfectly reasonable to handle incoming events with Cloud Functions, then proxy that work to Compute Engine.  You can even [start a configured Compute Engine instance programmatically](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/start) if need be.  I wouldn't expect that process to be fast, but then again, if you need 8 cores, you probably have a lot of work to do anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid AWS Lambda doesn't allow you to choose number of CPU cores. In the [Lambda configuration documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-console.html), it says under **Memory** section that:

> Memory– The amount of memory available to the function during execution. Choose an amount between 128 MB and 3,008 MB in 64-MB increments.
>
> Lambda allocates CPU power linearly in proportion to the amount of memory configured. At 1,792 MB, a function has the equivalent of one full vCPU (one vCPU-second of credits per second).

Google cloud functions also follows a similar model where memory & CPU power are connected (But hides the number of cores involved). You can see details [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#compute_time).

**UPDATE**

You could also try [Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run). It can be [configured](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu) for upto 2 vCPUs. And you only pay when your code is running, billed to the nearest 100 milliseconds